# Is it correct to say "cursed by someone"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Would it be right to say that "I'm cursed by someone" meaning that I'm totally addicted, extremely  in love etc.? Or what would be the right word? The word "charmed" seems not that intense. The whole sentence would be:

> Let me tell you a million and one time that I'm cursed by this one (introducing another person). Totally, and of mine own free will.

Does it all sound correct?

Comment: *cursed* doesn't quite work; *infatuated* does  but you may want something stronger

Comment: Maybe you’d like ***smitten***

Comment: ah, what could be other options in this case?

Comment: smitten might work, i'll think about it - thank you!

Comment: Try *enthralled*.

Comment: "Cursed by" implies that the other person is actively hostile towards you, which is presumably not what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you say that you're cursed by someone, it means that that person has actively put a curse on you, as a gypsy or voodoo priest might. This isn't what you want to convey.

There are other terms for the state you describe, but if you want to use the "curse" metaphor you could say that you're cursed by your love for the person.

Answer (score 0):

[Infatuated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/infatuated) is appropriate for intense but short lived feelings.  "I have a crush on someone" would also work.